# getAnnotations() is empty in ejb jar

Tags: java, maven, annotations, ejb-3.1

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create ejb project. (For example: Project1)
2. Create annotation class (For example: Test.class):

   ```
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface Test {

   }
   ```
3. Create a simple java project. (For example: Project2)
4. Add Project1 as an ejb dependency to Project2.
5. Create simple class (For example: TestModel) and apply @Test annotation to it:

   ```
   @Test
   public class TestModel {
       ...
   }
   ```
6. Create ear project. (For example: Project3)
7. Create ejb-module in Project3. (For example: Project3-ejb)
8. Add Project2 as a jar dependency to Project3-ejb.
9. Create stateless timer in Project3-ejb:

   ```
   @Stateless
   @LocalBean
   public class Timer {

       @Schedule(minute = "*", second = "*", hour = "*")

       public void myTimer() {
           try {
               System.out.println(TestModel.class.getAnnotations().length);
           } catch (SecurityException ex) {
               logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
10. Clean, build and deploy Project3 to glassfish 3 or 4.

In server output you will see 0. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this problem is specific only for glassfish servers. If I deploy Project3 to Jboss server, I will see 1 in the server output. Seems, this is glassfish bug. I created ticket: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20990
Also, if in step 4 add Project1 as jar dependency, I see 1 in server output.